# .htaccess redirecting a specific route with both https and http

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a `.htaccess` that does the following:

When i visit `https :// www.test.com/register/abc` it loads the file `https :// www.test.com/register/index.php?path=abc` (but still retains the url `https :// www.test.com/register/abc` on the browser)

So far, this is my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It works well if i visit the url already on https. 
The browser shows `www.test.com/register/abc`.

However, if i visit the url on http, the url on the browser shows as this `www.test.com/register/index.php?path=abc`

Technically, it still works but the url is really ugly. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what your looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) /index.php?path=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

It will internally rewrite:

`www.example.com/register/acb`  to 
 `www.example.com/index.php?path=abc`

Update: To force to https you couls use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) /index.php?path=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Just a quick question, what if I also want to redirect all http to https? The answer above works great but doesn't change http to https (i don't want any non-http urls)